# Balanced Expression

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, stack

Below is the code to determine balancing of symbol.

If the expression is balanced then it should print appropriate message. E.g:

```
((A+B))+(C+D)) --> Balanced

((A+B)+(C+D) ---> Unbalanced

((A+B)+(C+D}) --> Unbalanced
```

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Stack {
    char data;
    struct Stack *next;
};

void push(struct Stack **top, char data) {
    struct Stack *new_node;
    if (*top == NULL) {
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *top;
        *top = new_node;
    } else {
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *top;
        *top = new_node;
    }
}

char pop(struct Stack **top, int flag) {
    if (*top != NULL && flag == 0) {
        printf("\n Expression is In-Valid  :) \n");
        return '\0';
    }
    if (*top == NULL && flag == 1) {
        printf("\n Unbalanced Expression \n");
        return '\0';
    }
    if (*top != NULL && flag == 1) {
        struct Stack *temp = *top;
        char op;
        op = (*top)->data;
        *top = (*top)->next;
        free(temp);
        return op;
    }
}

/*
void display(struct Stack *top) {
    struct Stack *temp = top;
    while (temp) {
        printf("\n %c", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
*/

int main(void) {
    struct Stack *top = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "((A+B)+[C+D])", op;
    printf("\n Running the programe to check if the string is balanced or not ");
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '(' || str[i] == '[' || str[i] == '{' || str[i] == '<')
            push(&top, str[i]);
        else
        if (str[i] == ')' || str[i] == ']' || str[i] == '}' || str[i] == '>') {
            op = pop(&top, 1);
            if ((op == '(' && str[i] == ')') || 
                (op == '[' && str[i] == ']') ||
                (op == '{' && str[i] == '}') ||
                (op == '<' && str[i] == '>')) {
                continue;
            } else {
                printf("\n The expression is un-balanced \n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    pop(&top, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

But it does not give the desired output. I have debugged the code but was not able to find the issue.

How can I have it print the appropriate message ?

Comment: I don't see any print message saying `Balanced expression` or similar.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why the `if` in the `push` function? Both branches do the same thing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sir, maybe it is not _unrelated_ here ? A copy-paste one, that may _cost_ much.

Comment: Regarding your problem, what output do you get, and what do you expect? Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I think this code can be much simpler (without using stack or any fancy data structure) by using simple array & few counters - Just saying

Comment: @GauravSingh Stack is the way to implement it. Using an array and few counters won't solve the problem.

Comment: @vish4071 is it really the only way possible?

Comment: @GauravSingh, if it is possible by any other method, I'd like to know.

Comment: @vish Yes it is absolutely possible without Stack. As pointed out by Gaurav,  We could use array and a few counter. I wanted to write some Stack programming so that is why I have used a Stack

Comment: @GauravSingh, I really thought for a solution other than stack but could not come up with one. I'd like to see the code/pseudo-code if you please. A link on ideone or something would help.

Answer (score 1):

You should immediately clean the stack and stop processing as soon as you detect something unbalanced, and print "Balanced" when you reach return 0. And you should print "Unbalanced" from one single place in your code.

And it is bad that one branch of `pop` does not return a value when it is declared to return one.

So, `pop` could become:

```
char pop(struct Stack **top,int flag)
{
        if(*top!=NULL && flag==0)
        {
                return '\0';
        }
        if(*top==NULL && flag ==1)
        {
                return '\0';
        }
        if(*top!=NULL && flag==1)
        {
                struct Stack *temp=*top;
                char op;
                op=(*top)->data;
                *top=(*top)->next;
                free(temp);
                return op;
        }
        // *top == null && flag == 0
        return 'O'; // for OK
}
```

I would add a `clean` method - not required because program exit cleans the stack, but I do prefer that:

```
void clean(struct Stack *top) {
    struct Stack *next;
    while (top != NULL) {
        next = top->next;
        free(top);
        top = next;
    }
}
```

And some changes in main:

```
int main(void)
{
        struct Stack *top=NULL;
        int i=0, err=0;
        ...
                        else
                        {
                                err = 1;
                                break;
                        }

                }
        }
        if (err || (pop(&top,0) == '\0')) {
            printf("\n The expression is un-balanced \n");
            clean(top);
            // return 1; optionally if you want to return a different value to environment
        }
        else {
            printf("\n The expression is balanced \n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pop function is wrong.

You have not handled if `top` is `null` and `flag` is `0`. It might also be a case.

Secondly, why do you `**top` in your `push\pop` signature when you should be passing `top` in it. I think it should have `*top` in its signature.

Also, why you use `if` in `push`. Its not needed. You are essentially doing same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by simple modification in this code. I take it from [Find maximum depth of nested parenthesis in a string](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-maximum-depth-nested-parenthesis-string/) this. It's also help for knowing details. I think it's helpful to you

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function takes a string and returns the
// maximum depth nested parenthesis
int maxDepth(string S)
{
    int current_max = 0; // current count
    int max = 0;    // overall maximum count
    int n = S.length();

    // Traverse the input string
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        if (S[i] == '(')
        {
            current_max++;

            // update max if required
            if (current_max> max)
                max = current_max;
        }
        else if (S[i] == ')')
        {
            if (current_max>0)
                current_max--;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }

    // finally check for unbalanced string
    if (current_max != 0)
        return -1;

    return max;
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    string s = "( ((X)) (((Y))) )";
    if (maxDepth(s) == -1)    
        cout << "Unbalance";
    else 
        cout << "Balance";
    return 0;
}


Time Complexity : O(n)
Auxiliary Space : O(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Here is my below working code of the same problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Stack{
char data;
struct Stack *next;
};

void push(struct Stack **top,char data)
{
        struct Stack *new_node;
        new_node=malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
        new_node->data=data;
        new_node->next=*top;
        *top=new_node;
}
int compare(char str,char op)
{
        if( (op == '(' && str == ')') || (op == '{' && str == '}') || (op == '[' && str == ']') || (op == '<' && str == '>') )
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;
}
int pop(struct Stack **top,char str)
{
        char op,ret;
        struct Stack *temp=*top;
        if(*top==NULL)
                return 0;

        else if(*top!=NULL)
        {
                // Pop the element and then call comapre function
                op=(*top)->data;
                free(temp);
                *top=(*top)->next;
                return(ret=compare(str,op));
        }
}
void display(struct Stack *top)
{
        struct Stack *temp=top;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
                printf("%c ",temp->data);
                temp=temp->next;
        }
printf("\n");
}
int isNotEmpty(struct Stack *top)
{

        if(top!=NULL)
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
        struct Stack *top=NULL;
        int i=0,y,flag=0;
        char str[]="((A+B)+(C+D)>",op;
        printf("\n Running the programe to check if the string is balanced or not ");
        for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';++i)
        {
                if( str[i] == '(' || str[i] == '[' || str[i] == '{' || str[i] == '<' )
                        push(&top,str[i]);
                else if( str[i] == ')' || str[i] == ']' || str[i] == '}' || str[i] == '>')
                {
                        y=pop(&top,str[i]);
                        if(!y)
                        {
                                printf("\n Unbalanced Expression ");
                                flag=1;
                        }
                }
        }
        if(!flag)
        {
                if(isNotEmpty(top))
                        printf(" \nUnbalanced Expression ");
                else
                        printf(" \n Balanced Expression ");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it is super easy and easy to understand

```
package com.codewithsouma.stack;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Expression {

    private final List<Character> leftBrackets = Arrays.asList('(','{','[','<');
    private final List<Character> rightBrackets = Arrays.asList(')','}',']','>');

    public boolean isBalanced(String input) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (isLeftBracket(ch))
                stack.push(ch);

            if (isRightBracket(ch)) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) return false;

                char top = stack.pop();
                if (!bracketsMatch(top,ch)) return false;
            }
        }

        return stack.isEmpty();
    }

    private boolean isRightBracket(char ch) {
        return rightBrackets.contains(ch);
    }

    private boolean isLeftBracket(char ch) {
        return leftBrackets.contains(ch);
    }

    public boolean bracketsMatch(char left, char right){
        return leftBrackets.indexOf(left) == rightBrackets.indexOf(right);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, we create a hash table and store all brackets, left brackets are key and the value is its corresponding right brackets. Then we take an expression string from the user and create a character array. then we iterate the array and take a character then we check is this character left brackets or not if it is left bracket then we put into the stack (leftBracketContainer) otherwise we check is it the right bracket if right bracket then we pop the left bracket from the stack and find the closing bracket/ opposite bracket from the hash table and matching the current character/bracket if not matched ( for example our stack contain { this bracket so its closing bracket is } we find from the hash map and our current character = ] current character != opposite bracket ) `return false` otherwise we continue. At last when loop over then stack should empty. (if stack contain one more left bracket that means our expression needs another right bracket) if stack empty that means our expression is balanced otherwise not.

N:B when we check left bracket or not using `isItLeftBracket(ch)` then we check is our map contains the keys because all keys are left brackets like the ways we cheak right bracket by using `isItRightBracket(ch)` here we chake our map contains the value because all the value of the map are right bracket

```
package com.codewithsouma.stack;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Stack;
    
    public class BalancedExpressionUsingMap {
        private final Map<Character,Character> map;
    
        public BalancedExpressionUsingMap() {
            this.map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put('(',')');
            map.put('[',']');
            map.put('<','>');
            map.put('{','}');
        }
    
        public boolean isBalanced(String expression){
            Stack<Character> leftBracketContainer = new Stack<>();
            char [] arrayOfCharacter = expression.toCharArray();
            for (char ch : arrayOfCharacter) {
                if(isItLeftBracket(ch))
                    leftBracketContainer.push(ch);
                else if(isItRightBracket(ch)){
                    if(leftBracketContainer.isEmpty()) return false;
    
                    char leftBracket = leftBracketContainer.pop();
                    char oppositeBracket = getOppositeBracket(leftBracket);
                    if (oppositeBracket != ch) return false;
                }
            }
    
            return leftBracketContainer.isEmpty();
        }
    
        private char getOppositeBracket(char leftBracket) {
            return map.get(leftBracket);
        }
    
        private boolean isItRightBracket(char ch) {
            return map.containsValue(ch);
        }
    
        private boolean isItLeftBracket(char ch) {
            return map.containsKey(ch);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pleasy explain what your solution code do, don't just post the code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of allocating a stack for the delimiters, you can use a recursive function that skips balanced subexpressions and returns `NULL` upon mismatches:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *check(const char *s, char open) {
    while (*s) {
        switch (*s++) {
        case ')': return (open == '(') ? s : NULL;
        case ']': return (open == '[') ? s : NULL;
        case '}': return (open == '{') ? s : NULL;
        case '>': return (open == '<') ? s : NULL;
        case '(':
        case '[':
        case '{':
        case '<':
            s = check(s, s[-1]);
            if (s == NULL)
                return NULL;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (open) {
        /* closing delimiter not found */
        return NULL;
    }
    return s;
}

void test(const char *s) {
    printf("%s -> %s\n", s, check(s, 0) ? "Balanced" : "Unbalanced");
}

int main() {
    test("((A+B)+(C+D))");
    test("((A+B))+(C+D))");
    test("((A+B)+(C+D)");
    test("((A+B)+(C+D})");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
((A+B)+(C+D)) -> Balanced
((A+B))+(C+D)) -> Unbalanced
((A+B)+(C+D) -> Unbalanced
((A+B)+(C+D}) -> Unbalanced
```

Note that contrary to your assertion, `((A+B))+(C+D))` is unbalanced.